# composer outdated without install

Tags: composer-php

I'd like to fetch the composer.lock (& .json) from a project, and run some test to see if there is outdated packages in it.

the `composer outdated` seems to require me to install all packages first,
but that seams a bit overkill, as all needed information should be in the composer.lock-file.

1. Is there information avaible after an install, thats not avaible from the lock-file?
2. Is it posible to find outdated packages without running the `composer install`?

## Update 1

I take "foolz/sphinxql-query-builder" as an exemple from one project.

- In `composer.json` there is a
  `require['foolz/sphinxql-query-builder'] = '^1.0'`.
- In `composer.lock` there is a
  `packages[] = {name: foolz/sphinxql-query-builder, version: '1.0.2', ...}`
- In `~/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2018-04.json` there is a `providers['foolz/sphinxql-query-builder']->sha256`
- In `~/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-foolz\$sphinxql-query-builder.json` there is a
  `packages['foolz/sphinxql-query-builder']->$version`
- From that file i can run
  `array_keys((array) $json->packages->{'foolz/sphinxql-query-builder'})`
  to get a list of availible versions.

  3. So how do i fetch the latest 'provider-foolz\$sphinxql-query-builder.json' file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Composer.lock defines the exact versions of your packages, so only with this file you are not able to define if it is possible to upgrade the package to a new tag version
   For example, 
   In composer.json you have this version of package
   `"laravelium/sitemap": "^3.0",`

In composer lock there exists this information

```
{
            "name": "laravelium/sitemap",
            "version": "v3.0.1",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://gitlab.com/Laravelium/Sitemap.git",
                "reference": "b287ec4a6b47dcd63fd121199c05e059c479bc6f"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/Laravelium%2FSitemap/repository/archive.zip?sha=b287ec4a6b47dcd63fd121199c05e059c479bc6f",
                "reference": "b287ec4a6b47dcd63fd121199c05e059c479bc6f",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "illuminate/support": "5.7.*",
                "php": ">=7.1.3"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "orchestra/testbench": "3.7.*",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "extra": {
                "laravel": {
                    "providers": [
                        "Laravelium\\Sitemap\\SitemapServiceProvider"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-0": {
                    "Laravelium\\Sitemap": "src/"
                }
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Roumen Damianoff",
                    "email": "roumen@damianoff.com",
                    "homepage": "https://damianoff.com",
                    "role": "Developer"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Laravelium Sitemap package for Laravel.",
            "homepage": "https://laravelium.com",
            "keywords": [
                "Sitemap",
                "generator",
                "google-news",
                "html",
                "laravel",
                "laravelium",
                "php",
                "xml"
            ],
            "time": "2018-09-04T19:08:44+00:00"
        },
```

Note, that you will install version v3.{\d+} (>=3 && <4) if it exists, and new tag version may have incompatible change

2. `composer show -l` returns the list of packages. Coloured red packages can be updated, and colored green are on the latest version.

Nevertheless, you steel need to proceed with `composer install`, because only this way you can understand the exact versions of installed packages

Comment: The file you pasted it not a `composer.json`-file. It's a `composer.lock`-file. `composer.lock` contains the exact version installed, otherwise `composer install` wouldn't work consistently across systems. Information from the repository and the lock-file should be enough.

Comment: @Nasso yes, thank you, it is a misspell, I've meant, that composer.lock has that information

Comment: Your comment states "But in composer json there exists this information" and the following text is a `composer.lock`-file. The `composer.lock`-file contains the exact version of packages that should be installed. That makes your last sentance  "Nevertheless, you steel need to proceed with composer install, because only this way you can understand the exact versions of installed packages" wrong. You don't need `composer install` know know the exact version. The exact version of everything installed in in the `composer.lock`-file.

Comment: Composer.json contains the information about packages according to semver specification. For example, you can write in your composer.json “laravelium/sitemap”: “^3.0”, that means, that you can install any version of this library between 3.0 and 3.1 (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-) at the same time composer.lock will contain the version which was actual when you first time execute composer install/update command. In this case you can have any version between this range (the newest bugfix version according to semver)